# installing charm using conda not able to get packages

Tags: conda, charm

I am trying to install charm-crypto package using conda. But, it gives me the following error:

Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- charm

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/r/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
  ...

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

From which site can I get the charm-crypto package?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try pip install charm-crypto

Comment: What is the exact command you're using?

Comment: @darthbith I tried the following commands: conda install charm-crypto-0.43, conda install charm-crypto-0.42 and even, conda install charm. But, no success.

Comment: @An student I tried using this the command pip install charm-crypto also. But, dint work. Instead it gave me the error as :  Building wheel for charm-crypto (setup.py) ... error and error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for charm-crypto